# Javascript code getoption

Tags: javascript

> Write a function getoption(m,i) which takes a parameter m, a string of
>   words seperated by comma ",", and an integer i≥-1 and returns the ith
>   word in m. If i=-1, then a random word is returned else the ith word
>   is returned. No error checking is required.
>
> For example, getoption("hello,hi,why,ok",1) must return hello.
>
> `getoption("hello,hi,why,ok",4)` must return ok.
>
> `getoption("hello,hi,why,ok",-1)` MAY return either hello, hi, who OR
>   ok.
>
> Hint: You need to split the string m by character ",". This will
>   result in an array of words. Remember the first word will be index
>   0!!!! Now if i is greater than -1, return element i+1 since again the
>   starting index of the array is 0. If i=-1 then generated a random
>   number from 0 to array.length-1 and then return the word corresponding
>   to this number.

Hello, I have written the code below and I have a typeerror on line 6 and I don't know how to fix it. Can someone help?

```js
function getoption(m, i) {
  var num = m + Math.floor((m + 1) * Math.random());
  var j = i.indexOf(num);

  while (j != -1) {
    num = m + Math.floor((m + 1) * Math.random());
    j = i.indexOf(num);
  }

  return (num);
}

document.write(getoption("hello,hi,why,ok", -1))
```

Comment: i is a number. Only arrays and string have indexOf

Comment: Your function is too complex. Start by `var list = m.split(",")` then test the number passed and if it is -1 grab a random word from the list, else return list[i]. You do NOT need indexOf here. Use the list.length to calculate the random number

Comment: Seems like your idea is to get the index `return (num)` but the exercise said that you need to return a word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a wanted result, I suggest to split the string into a word array with [`String#split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and store it in an appropriate variable.

Then I suggest to check if the index is equal `-1` and get a new index with the length of the array and [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random).

Now return the element with the index of the word array.

```js
function getoption(words, index) {
    var wordArray = words.split(',');
    if (index === -1) {
        index = Math.floor(Math.random() * wordArray.length);
    }
    return wordArray[index];
}

document.write(getoption("hello,hi,why,ok", -1))
```

Comment: when i put in index 4 it returns undefined instead of ok.

Comment: @Misa, thats right, because indices of arrays are [zero based](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Accessing_array_elements). if you take `index = 0`, the it returns `'hello'`, which is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce your function to more simpler way.

Try something like that:

```js
function getoption(m, i) {
  var words = m.split(",");
  
  if (i == -1) {
    i = Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length);
  }
  return words[i];
}

document.write(getoption("hello,hi,why,ok",-1));
document.write("<br>");
document.write(getoption("hello,hi,why,ok",0));
document.write("<br>");
document.write(getoption("hello,hi,why,ok",2));
```

I hope that helps :D

Comment: when I put in index 4 it returns undefined instead of ok.  getoption("hello,hi,why,ok",4) must return ok.

Comment: Because is index 0 based. If `document.write(getoption("hello,hi,why,ok",0))` is **hello**, then `document.write(getoption("hello,hi,why,ok",3))` is **ok**